# Why does this method for solving cubics seem to fail?

Tags: proof-verification, indefinite-integrals, inverse-function, cubics

I was trying to see if I could apply the method below to solve a certain subclass of the class of cubic equations with only one real root, and I came up with a block whose cause I couldn't find.

OK, so let $$y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d,$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real and $a\ne 0.$ Then $y'=3ax^2+2bx+c.$ Now the plan is to consider those cubics as defined above for which $y'$ has the same sign for all $x.$ This would ensure that an inverse function $$x=f(y)$$ exists, and the plan is to get this function by integration. Let's continue.

Now, for $y'>0,$ without loss of generality, we must have $(2b)^2-4(3a)c\lt 0,$ or $$3ac-b^2>0.$$ Thus, with $k^2=3ac-b^2,$ we have $$y'=3a\left[\left(x+\frac{b}{3a}\right)^2+\frac{k^2}{9a^2}\right],$$ by attempting to complete squares. It then follows, since $y'\ne 0$ for all $x,$ that $$x=\int{\frac{\mathrm d y}{3a\left[\left(y+\frac{b}{3a}\right)^2+\frac{k^2}{9a^2}\right]}}$$ exists for all $y.$ This integral can be easily evaluated to give $$\frac1k \arctan{\left(\frac{3ay}{k}+\frac{b}{k}\right)}+C.$$ To determine the constant $C,$ note that with the original equation, we have $y=d$ when $x=0,$ so that we have $$C=-\frac1k \arctan{\left(\frac{3ad}{k}+\frac{b}{k}\right)},$$ so that $$x=\frac1k \arctan{\left(\frac{3ay}{k}+\frac{b}{k}\right)}-\frac1k \arctan{\left(\frac{3ad}{k}+\frac{b}{k}\right)}.$$

It is now an easy matter to find the real root $x$ of the original equation, which is the value of $x$ when $y=0.$ This gives the number $$x=\frac1k \arctan{\left(\frac{b}{k}\right)}-\frac1k \arctan{\left(\frac{3ad}{k}+\frac{b}{k}\right)}.$$

Now consider applying this procedure to the example $$2x^3+3x^2+2x+3=0.$$ Clearly $3^2-3(2)(2)<0,$ so it is of the required type. Also, it is easy to see that it has only one real root, namely $x=-3/2.$ However, applying the method above, we obtain $k=\sqrt 3,$ so that the root as given by the arctangent should be $$x=\frac {1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan{\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt 3}\right)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan{\left(\frac{21}{\sqrt 3}\right)}.$$ If this is so, then we must have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan{\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt 3}\right)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan{\left(\frac{21}{\sqrt 3}\right)}=-\frac 3 2,$$ which gives $$\arctan{(7\sqrt 3)}-\arctan{\sqrt 3}=\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2},$$ which is clearly false.

I have checked again and again, but have failed to see where I went wrong. Please help me spot the false step. Many thanks!

*PS.* This method works seamlessly well with equations of first order, as can be easily checked; so I kept wondering where the analogy breaks down.

Comment: Interesting approach. Could it be applied to quadratic equations? Just wondering how was "c" calculated in the expression: y'=3a[...] near the top? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious: how did you obtain that $$x=\int{\frac{\mathrm d y}{3a\left[\left(y+\frac{b}{3a}\right)^2+\frac{k^2}{9a^2}\right]}}?$$

Comment: I guess this would be from the definition of the inverse function x=f(y).

Comment: @NoChance Do you mean the integration constant? If so I used the original equation $y=p(x),$ where $p(x)$ is the cubic polynomial in OP.

Comment: @YiFan The strictly positive derivative $y'$ assures us that there is an inverse $y\mapsto x,$ and the derivative of this inverse is given by $1/y',$ from calculus. Thus one of the primitives of $1/y'$ is the inverse. I pinpointed it by using the condition that $p(0)=d,$ where $p(x)$ is the cubic polynomial on the RHS of the first equation above.

Comment: @NoChance As to your question about quadratics, I'd applied it to that case too but thought the problem was with the fact that the derivative of a quadratic vanishes at some point. Hence my using the example of cubics of the above form, which satisfy every conceivable hypothesis needed for the theorems to apply, yet has failed to produce the correct solution, as it should. If I get an answer to the cubic case, then I will probably be more motivated to consider the quadratic further. But this method (if it works) is obviously well-suited only for equations of odd degree with only one real root.

Comment: Error. It should be $k^2 =3ac-b^2$.

Comment: @stevengregory Oh, my. Thank you. That's what I'd meant to type -- I actually used the correct form in my work, as you can confirm. That is, this error is not the source of the discrepancy described. I will presently correct it.

Comment: But wait. You said “$\arctan(7\sqrt3\,)-\arctan\sqrt3=$” some algebraic number. This is inconceivable, since $\arctan\sqrt3=\pi/3$. How did you get that evaluation?

Comment: @Lubin If you start reading the sentence where I wrote that equation from the beginning, you'd notice that it is a conditional, beginning, *If this is so...* Furthermore, I ended it with the admission that this is clearly false. This was what prompted my question, since obviously something must be wrong someplace.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t explain myself clearly enough. You got an inconceivable value for the difference of two arctans. I was not complaining about your method of trying to solve the cubic.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, indeed. That was why I thought something must be wrong with the method, but I couldn't find what, so I asked for help.

Comment: I was being stupid, I see. Ignore all my comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope you can continue with your method.

Comment: @NoChance Thanks, but the hope may be frail. Since the problem has been pointed out (and it's not a trivial one), it turns out the transformation I was effecting changes the problem into another one of comparable difficulty, if not more. In general this transformation changes the equation $y=p(x)$ into a differential equation in $x,$ which one hopes to solve explicitly. But this is not in general possible, especially so since beyond the linear polynomial equation we get nonlinear differential equations; what I was trying to do above, for example, is equivalent to solving for $x=f(y)$ in...

Comment: (*continued from above*)... $$\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y}=\frac{1}{3ax^2+2bx+c}.$$ Clearly, this is heavily nonlinear and doesn't look like it can allow $x$ be expressed as a combination of elementary functions. However, I may root around for a bit more. But I don't think I have sufficient motivation to carry on along this line. It was only a passing curiosity.

Comment: Well, your idea is interesting, you will come up with something since you have good brains. This last equation may be written as follows (I guess): $\int \:dx=x+c1=\int \frac{dy}{Ax^2+Bx+c\:}=\frac{y}{ax^2+bx+c}+c2$

Comment: Try the standard cubic formula  $$x=\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{b}{3a}$$

Comment: @poetasis Thanks, but I knew about it and that wasn't what my question was about. In any case I have my answer already. Again, thank you.

Comment: I wish this approach was useful for quintics too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The observation of @YiFan is right.

You actually have
$$
\eqalign{
  & y' = 3a\left( {\left( {x + {b \over {3a}}} \right)^{\,2}  + {{k^{\,2} } \over {\left( {3a} \right)^{\,2} }}} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad dx = {{dy} \over {3a\left( {\left( {x + {b \over {3a}}} \right)^{\,2}  + {{k^{\,2} } \over {\left( {3a} \right)^{\,2} }}} \right)}} \cr} 
$$
where you shall read the $x$ at the denominator as $x(y)$.

Comment: My thinking was this: I integrated $1/y'$ from some fixed point $p$ to a variable $y.$ That is, I treated the $x$ in the denominator as a dummy variable. That is equivalent to seeking a primitive and using FTC as displayed above, isn't it? But I appreciate your input. Will look into it.

Comment: @Allawonder: You can't just wishfully turn $x$ into $y$. This is meaningless.

Comment: @Allawonder:  " .. I treated the $x$ in the denominator as a dummy variable  .." : you can't, it depends on $y$ !

Comment: Yes, I have convinced myself that this was indeed where my problem was. Turns out there's no easy way here too, beyond the linear equations, which is nothing doing. Alright, thank you.

Comment: @Allawonder:  sorry I had to pin down that, because otherwise your "plan of attack" was interesting.

Comment: @GCab Pin down what? If you mean the error, then you shouldn't be sorry -- in any case I'm not, because otherwise my question would have remained unanswered. I *knew* there was something wrong (as explained in OP) just that I didn't spot it. It was exactly so someone could spot my mistake or wrong assumption for me that I asked the question. Thankfully someone did. And I'm satisfied that that's indeed what caused the antinomy described in OP. The approach to the cubic itself is a little matter, when you come to think of it. It was just a passing thought.